# Trying to spawn enemies in a circle around the player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

2D sidescroller. I'm trying to instantiate 5 Enemy prefabs around the player following a circle, surrounding him. Ive been using the player position to create the radius but I cant figure it out.

Any ideas?

Here's an image of my goal:
[image]

> Position your prefab above your player, however far away you'd like with whatever radius.
>
> Calculate how much of an angle you'd need to rotate for however many enemies you'd like to instantiate. So if you want 5 enemies, you could go like:
>
> float angle = 360f / 5;
>   Use Transform.RotateAround to rotate your prefab around your player by angle however many times, and Instantiate a copy of the prefab. This way you'll get a perfect circle.
>
> Alternatively, if you didn't want to use RotateAround, you could have your single prefab as a child of a gameObject, change the child's transform.localPosition to be whatever distance from its parent's center, then Rotate the prefab's parent transform by angle 5 times.

I slowly worked my way into a workable solution with his instructions. I'm sure there's a prettier way to do it, and Id love to hear other inputs, but this works just fin. Here's what I'm doing:

```
private int num_enemies=5;
float angle =  360f/5;
void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
     //emptyenemy is a gameobject I have positioned right on top of the player
    //This is hardcoded and needs to change to position itself betwwen the player and the top of the screen

            Vector3 enemyPos = emptyEnemy.transform.position;

    while (num_enemies>0) {
        Instantiate (EnemyPrefab, enemyPos, player.transform.rotation);
        EnemyPrefab.tag = "Enemy" + num_enemies;
        num_enemies--;
        emptyEnemy.transform.RotateAround (player.transform.position, Vector3.forward, angle);
        enemyPos=emptyEnemy.transform.position;
    }
}
```

I'm going to be playing around with this, trying to make them orbit and what not. Id love to hear other peoples approaches as well.

Comment: You'll want to post at least a little sample or description of the attempts you've made so far.  Any kind of pattern perhaps.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the circle algorithm, or instantiation? With position on the screen, or position relative to your game-state model? We need more info about your project!

Comment: I can Instantiate just fine, the problem is directly with the players poistion relative to the screen size and casting a circle of enemies around him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple ways you might do this:

---

1. Create a `parentGameObject` game object.
2. Create 5 child gameObjects; position them where you want the instantiations to be positioned.
3. Make `parentGameObject.transform.position` be equal to your player's `transform.position`.
4. Loop through each child transform and `Instantiate` your enemy prefab for each child transform:

   ```
   foreach (Transform child in parentGameObject.transform) {
       Instantiate(yourPrefab, child.position, Quaternion.identity);
   }
   ```

or

---

1. Position your prefab above your player, however far away you'd like with whatever radius.
2. Calculate how much of an angle you'd need to rotate for however many enemies you'd like to instantiate. So if you want 5 enemies, you could go like:

   ```
   float angle = 360f / 5;
   ```
3. Use [Transform.RotateAround](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) to rotate your prefab around your player by `angle` however many times, and `Instantiate` a copy of the prefab. This way you'll get a perfect circle.

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use `RotateAround`, you could have your single prefab as a child of a gameObject, change the child's `transform.localPosition` to be whatever distance from its parent's center, then [`Rotate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) the prefab's parent transform by `angle` 5 times.